# Can I integrate HMS nearby Service and analytics kit into my Unity Game? and How?

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

I want to add HMS nearby Service and analytics kit into my unity Game, I read through a few Q&As here but those answers are here and there, not complete.  Could anyone tell me what I really need to do so to integrate them into my code properly? thanks

Answer (score 0):

For overall procedures as to how to deploy your Unity Game into Huawei App. Gallery, please refer to the official documentation at: https://api-udp.unity.com/guideDoc/HUAWEI

The easiest way to integrate HMS Kits into your unity Game, you can use HMS Unity Plugin. The HMS Unity Plugin is a tool that helps developers to quickly integrate Huawei Mobile Services (HMS) to their games in Unity without worrying about the boilerplate codes that have to be written in the background. All the necessary backend code is dealt with for you, and all you have to do is to focus on your own game and HMS features.

Huawei plugin’s GitHub page is at: https://github.com/EvilMindDevs/hms-unity-plugin/tree/2.0 Please make sure to download the latest version of the plugin for the corresponding Unity version.

1. To start using the plugin you must go to [link](https://github.com/EvilMindDevs/hms-unity-plugin/tree/2.0#1---register-your-app-at-huawei-developer), for the readme of the official GitHub page of the plugin and complete the phases, starting from the phase called “1 — Register your app at Huawei Developer” to “4 — Connect your game with any HMS Kit”, so that the AppGallery Connect side of your application is done. HMS requires AppGallery Connect configurations to correctly work with the in-game features you want to implement.
2. Currently available HMS Kits in Huawei plugin are:
   [image]
3. To use any kit, you must import the plugin (downloaded from the releases page) and click on the kits that you want to use. One example:

[image]

4. Configure your manifest
5. Connect your game with the HMS Managers
6. Connect the HMS Callbacks with your game